# Exterior algebra question

Tags: differential-forms, exterior-algebra, exterior-derivative

I don't know how to approach this question from Flanders' Differential Forms. I see it was discussed [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2562380/every-2-vector-is-decomposable-in-a-1-wedge-a-2-cdots-a-r-1-wedge-a-r), but I don't believe that argument is correct and would apply to something like $2v_1 \wedge v_2+3v_1 \wedge v_3+6v_2 \wedge v_3$)

Let L be an n-dimensional space and $\alpha$ a 2-vector. Show that there is a basis $\sigma_1,\cdots,\sigma_n$ of L such that

$\alpha=\sigma_1\wedge\sigma_2 + \cdots + \sigma_{2r-1}\wedge \sigma_{2r}..$

Show that $\alpha^r\ne0$ and  $\alpha^{r+1}=0$

I'm not sure if the book even defines what $\alpha^r$ means.

Comment: $\alpha^r := \alpha \wedge \alpha \wedge...\wedge \alpha$ $r$ times.

Comment: Also, if you let $w_1 = 3v_1 + 6v_2, w_2 = \frac{2}{3}v_2 + v_3$, you will see that your form is $w_1 \wedge w_2.$ I am not sure where his argument comes from, but there is a rigorous way to do this by representing the 2-form as a skew symmetric matrix $A$, and noting that basis changes for forms basically means mapping $A$ to $PAP^T$, where $P$ is an invertible matrix. The standard add one row to another operation we use for Gaussian elimination correspond to adding  the $i$th row to the $j$th row, and the $i$th column to the $j$th column.

Comment: Isn't $\alpha\wedge\alpha$ automatically $0$?

Comment: @Sam No, consider a basis $e_1, e_2, e_3, e_4$ and $\alpha = e_1\wedge e_2 + e_3\wedge e_4$. The alternation property $\alpha\wedge\alpha = 0$ is only necessarily true when $\alpha$ is vector, or more generally when it has a vector factor.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are working with differential forms on $L$, the exterior algebra you would normally use is $\bigwedge(L^*)$, thought of as spaces of alternating multilinear maps on $V$. In particular, $\bigwedge^2(L^*)$ is viewed as the space of alternating bilinear maps on $L$. (Since you can view $\bigwedge^2(L)$ as alternating bilinear maps on $L^*$, however, this isn't an  important distinction for the question you ask, but I find it easier to think about the bilinear maps!)

One way to show the result is to use induction on $\dim(L)$:

Given any $\alpha \in \bigwedge^2(L^*)$, then if $\alpha=0$, $r=0$ and there is nothing to prove. Otherwise, we may find $v_1,v_2\in L$ such that $\alpha(v_1,v_2)=-\alpha(v_2,v_1)\neq 0$. Rescaling $v_1$ as necessary, we may assume that $\alpha(v_1,v_2)=1$. Let $H_1 =\text{span}\{v_1,v_2\}$. Then if $H_1^{\perp} = \{v \in L: \alpha(v,h)=0, \forall h \in H_1\}$, and we take an arbitrary $v\in L$, then if we set
$$
h_v = \alpha(v,v_2)v_1 +\alpha(v_1,v)v_2 \in H_1,
$$
we have $\alpha(v,v_2) = \alpha(h_v,v_2)$ and $\alpha(v_1,h_v) = \alpha(v_1,v)$, so that $v = h_v+ (v-h_v)$ and $v-h_v \in H_1^{\perp}$ and thus it follows that $L= H_1 \oplus H_1^{\perp}$.

Now on $H_1$, if $\delta_1,\delta_2$ denote the dual basis to $\{v_1,v_2\}$ then it is clear that $\alpha_{|H_1} = \delta_1\wedge \delta_2$. Moreover, by definition, $\alpha(v,w)=0$ if $v\in H_1, w \in H_1^{\perp}$, so that $\alpha$ is completely determined by its restrictions to $H_1$ and $H_1^{\perp}$.

But since $\dim(H_1^{\perp})\leq \dim(L)-2$, by induction we know that there is a basis $\{v_3,\ldots,v_n\}$ of $H_1^{\perp}$, such that $\alpha_{|H_1^{\perp}} = f_3\wedge f_4+ \ldots + \ldots f_{2r-1}\wedge f_{2r}$. But then it follows that $\alpha = \sum_{i=1}^r f_{2i-1}\wedge f_{2i}$ as required.

Finally, it is clear that $\alpha^r= r!f_1\wedge\ldots f_{2r} \neq 0$, and $\alpha^{r+1}=0$ since it is a $2r+2$-form, which evidently can only be nonvanishing on $V$, but as $\dim(V)=2r$, all alternating forms of degree greater than $2r$ vanish.